# $\frac{\sin(t)}{t} = \prod_{m=1}^{+\infty} \cos(\frac{t}{2^m})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Show that $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}  = \prod_{m=1}^{+\infty} \cos(\frac{t}{2^m})$

I know that $\sin(t) = 2\sin(\frac{t}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2})$. Then, $\frac{\sin(t)}{t} = \frac{2}{t}\sin(\frac{t}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2})$

Comment: If you apply the same identity again to the $\sin(x/2)$ term you get $\sin(x) = 2\cos(x/2)\color{red}{\sin(x/2)} = 2\cos(x/2)[\color{red}{2\cos(x/4)\sin(x/4)}]$ and now you continue to apply it again to $\sin(x/4)$. The pattern we see from this is that $\sin(x) = 2^n\cos(x/2)\cos(x/2^2)\cdots \cos(x/2^n)\cdot \sin(x/2^n)$ and you can try to prove this using induction.

Answer (score 1):

$$P=\prod_{m=1}^{n} \cos(\frac{t}{2^m})=\cos(\frac{t}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2^2})\cdots\cos(\frac{t}{2^n})\cdot\frac{\sin(\frac{t}{2^n})}{\sin(\frac{t}{2^n})}=\frac{\sin t\cdot\frac{t}{2^n}\cdot \frac{1}{t}}{\sin{\frac{t}{2^n}}}$$

Thus:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to+\infty}P=\frac{\sin t}{t}.$$